# Algolia react-instantsearch : Are you experiencing lag while typing on SearchBox Filter?

Tags: algolia

I just noticed that typing on the  filter can by laggy/slow sometimes.
Are you guys experiencing it too?

Comment: Hi! Do you have a live-example that reproduce the issue? Do you experience the lag with a specific query?

Comment: you can take a look on this : https://dubai.dubizzle.com/motors/used-cars/

Comment: @vvo you want live example? Go ahead to their own RN tutorial. This is best ever example of inefficient ineffective slow application. Algolia on RN is real trash

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why, your url is synced constantly while the user is typing. I do not recommend you doing so because it's most of the time very laggy (browsers seems to dislike updating the url bar that much).

There's an example in react-instantsearch documentation about this: https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/tree/master/packages/react-instantsearch/examples/react-router-v4

You will be able to dig into App.js and see where we use a threshold of 700ms before updating the url.

Comment: thank you. i can put a debounce on that. but how about the checkboxes in filters?

Comment: I think that should work the same, what you want to debug is only the url syncing, when you type or click on facet it will still refine immediately. But it will only be synced to the url after 700ms. Which from our experience is always OK.